# Why change the appearance of my main menu in customer page?

Tags: magento2

does anyone please know why the appearance (the rules of my css file are not followed) and the behavior of the main menu changes on the page of creating a new user in Magento 2.4. My main menu is made up of product categories and submenus for product subcategories; But when entering the page to add a new user, the submenus do not appear and the menu options change their appearance and behavior, for example hover does not work. Thank you

Comment: Give a screenshot.. I think your Magento instance has some customization that why this happens

Comment: Thank you for your interest, I'm using a customization of Luma theme, I've created a child theme, I couldn't find a solution for this problem, whenever I use whatever link of customer options my main menu change its behavior I realized that change its css class so It change the way it looks. Please I will appreciate if you or someone else give me a tip about this I've spent a lot of time trying to find a solution.

Thank you

Comment: I forgot add to say I've tried changing  customer_account.xlm, customer_account_index.xlm, layout.xlm (theme layout) but without success